# Datatables pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have this code:

```
$('#ldap-users, #audit-users').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "bInfo": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate"  : true,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    'aaSorting': [[1, "desc" ]],
});
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_iDisplayStart' of null
```

When i click pagination button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by

```
"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
```

Remove / comment that line and you are ok. Guess you need the nessecary plugin, see ->
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination which says :

> Note that this plug-in uses the fnPagingInfo API plug-in method to
>   obtain paging information

The sourcecode for that plugin is listed below.

Comment: on my side. selected page is not getting marked as selected. commenting mentioned line is not helping

Answer (score 0):

The , after the last entry (aaSorting) is wrong. Remove it and try it again.

Comment: I remove it but i still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_iDisplayStart' of null`